# Using an SQL Parameter for the column name in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, switch-statement

I am using SQL parameters to allow the user to create their own `SELECT` query using dropdowns in the view. The parameter values are passed to the stored procedure from the view using entity framework in an MVC controller. SQL Parameters cannot be directly used for column names so I decided to use a case statement. The issue is that no data is getting returned so their must be some error in how I am using the statement.

```
    @topLeftInput varchar(100),
    @topRightInput varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
        Select  * from test
            where 
                CASE @topRightInput 
                    WHEN 'BasicReturnReasonId' THEN BasicReturnReasonId
                    WHEN 'ClientName' THEN ClientName
                    WHEN 'CreditDeniedReasonId' THEN CreditDeniedReasonId
                    WHEN 'ItemsnotReturnedReasonId' THEN ItemsnotReturnedReasonId
                    WHEN 'ManufacturerId' THEN ManufacturerId
                    WHEN 'ManufacturerOrderNumber' THEN ManufacturerOrderNumber
                    WHEN 'ProductConditionId' THEN ProductConditionId
                                ELSE NULL
                    END
                = @topRightInput;
END
```

Where the values coming in would be 'ProductConditionId' and '3', respectively.

I did have this working when I was using an if statement for the whole query, but it was overkill and entirely too long (Doesn't look like it because I cut it down for the sake of an example).

Here is an example of what I was doing for the first option:

```
if @topLeftInput = 'BasicReturnReasonId'
    Begin
        Select * from test
            where BasicReturnReasonId = @topRightInput;
    End
```

How can I get this working with the case statement?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, just realized this was just a typo and should be closed. `@topRightInput` should have been `@topLeftInput`. Works fine when the change was made. Still early and I just missed it :/

Comment: Here is a little tip that can possibly help you considerably later. Often times (but apparently not always). It is much better to declare a local variable, define it to the value of the input parameter, and use the local variable in your queries. Directly using the input parameter can cause a re-compile problem that I've found slows sprocs down by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

A simple technique you can use:

```
DECLARE @QUERY as varchar(max);
SET @QUERY='Select  * from test where '+ @topLeftInput +' = '+@topRightInput + ' ;'
EXEC(@QUERY)
```

**NB:** This method is vulnerable to sql injection. So, make sure you use proper validations.

Comment: **Warning** this vulnerable to sql-injection.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
    @topLeftInput varchar(100),
    @topRightInput varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'Select  * from test
             where ' + 
            CASE @topLeftInput 
                WHEN 'BasicReturnReasonId'      THEN QUOTENAME(N'BasicReturnReasonId')
                WHEN 'ClientName'               THEN QUOTENAME(N'ClientName')
                WHEN 'CreditDeniedReasonId'     THEN QUOTENAME(N'CreditDeniedReasonId')
                WHEN 'ItemsnotReturnedReasonId' THEN QUOTENAME(N'ItemsnotReturnedReasonId')
                WHEN 'ManufacturerId'           THEN QUOTENAME(N'ManufacturerId')
                WHEN 'ManufacturerOrderNumber'  THEN QUOTENAME(N'ManufacturerOrderNumber')
                WHEN 'ProductConditionId'       THEN QUOTENAME(N'ProductConditionId')
            END
          + N' = @topRightInput;'

exec sp_executesql @sql
                  ,N'@topRightInput varchar(100)'
                  ,@topRightInput

END
```

If the parameter `@topLeftInput` has the exact value for the column name then it is even simpler

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
    @topLeftInput varchar(100),
    @topRightInput varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'Select  * from test
             where ' +  QUOTENAME(@topLeftInput)  + N' = @topRightInput;'

exec sp_executesql @sql
                  ,N'@topRightInput varchar(100)'
                  ,@topRightInput

END
```